# how to kill sql query in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

Are there any useful way to kill sql query in apache ignite? can I kill query by rest api in ignite?
In apche ignite documents, I saw request http://host:port/ignite?cmd=qrycls&qryId={queryId}
to close sql query in ignite, but it doese not work for me, I can't find qryId

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [SQL command](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/operational-commands#kill-query):

```
KILL QUERY {ASYNC} 'query_id'
```

Or using the control.sh script:

```
./control.sh --kill SQL query_id
```

Or using the QueryMXBean JMX bean.

Note that the `qrycls` REST endpoint is not the same thing, and cannot be used to kill a query. It *closes* a query that was started with the `qryfldexe` or `qryscanexe` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the query_id with the following [SQL](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/system-views#sql_queries):

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.SQL_QUERIES
```